# How to trigger onAppear when returning from fullScreenCover

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swift3

onAppear doesn't trigger

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProfileViewViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if let user = viewModel.user {
                    profile(user: user)
                } else {
                    Text("Loading Profile...")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchUser() //this is the problem
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.showingPreview) {
            PreviewAvatarView()
        }
    }
}
```

I realized that onAppear didn't trigger when I dismiss fullscreencover.

Comment: Why do you need it to?  If `PreviewAvatarView` has changed he user, then this should be reflected by the model - pass the model object to the preview view

Comment: How about using ```onDisappear``` on ```PreviewAvatarView```?

Comment: @Paulw11 I save the image in firebase so i need it to update url to display the avatar. If not, i must switch back and forth among views to trigger onAppear instead.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I use viewmodel to separate logic and view so it's not a good way.

Comment: You are unnecessarily incurring network operation costs. Yes, you are saving the avatar in firebase, but your model can also be aware of this change. Your model is an observable object which should be shared to the sub views. It can use snapshot listeners and similar to publish changes and your view will update automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onAppear` doesn’t trigger because your underlying view is not appearing – the view that is covering it is going away, which isn’t the same thing.

However, `fullScreenCover` has a rarely-used optional argument, `onDismiss`, which may fulfil your needs, e.g.:

```swift
.fullScreenCover(
  isPresented: $viewModel.showingPreview,
  onDismiss: { viewModel.fetchUser() }
) {
  PreviewAvatarView()
}
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:))

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `onAppear` you can use `task`.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProfileViewViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if let user = viewModel.user {
                    profile(user: user)
                } else {
                    Text("Loading Profile...")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
        }
        .task(id: viewModel.showingPreview) {
            guard !viewModel.showingPreview else {return} //Check for false
    
            viewModel.fetchUser() //this is the problem
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.showingPreview) {
            PreviewAvatarView()
        }
    }
}
```

`task` will run `onAppear` and when the `Bool` is `false`.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried and it actually did

Comment: Also remove the unnecessary state object

Comment: @malhal that is still something I don’t agree with you I think Apple makes it clear every year that VMs are a choice [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/maintaining-a-local-copy-of-server-data) is yet another example

Comment: Unfortunately the Core Data team has never been good at UI code and this is another depressing example. View state shouldnt be centralised like that because it means the View hierarchy invalidation isn't efficient. And @State with a class is currently a memory leak because the init is not autoclosure, it briefly was in an early beta and removed.

Comment: @malhal if there is a leak you should report but State and Observable are designed to work together. Observables can be put into the Environment now like any other struct.

Comment: FB13015569: Instance of @⁠Observable class is leaked when used as @⁠State property in a View https://mastodon.social/@okla@mas.to/110915814230311764

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProfileViewViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if let user = viewModel.user {
                    profile(user: user)
                } else {
                    Text("Loading Profile...")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchUser() //this is the problem
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.showingPreview) {
            PreviewAvatarView()
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.showingPreview) { isFullScreenOpen in
            if !isFullScreenOpen {
                viewModel.fetchUser()
            }//Executed only when full screen cover is closed.
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the sheet closes the viewModel.fetchUser() will be executed.